# Use MySQL to create a string out of a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, function

What I'm hoping to do is create a string out of a table **WITHIN a query** so that I may be able to place that string in another query I'm creating.  Say, I have this for a table:

```
index | position   | name
----------------------------------------
1     | member     | John Smith
2     | chair      | Mary Jones
3     | member     | Mary Jones
4     | contact    | Grace Adams
5     | director   | Grace Adams
6     | member     | Grace Adams
7     | treasurer  | Bill McDonnell
8     | vice chair | Bill McDonnell
9     | member     | Ishmael Rodriguez
```

I'm looking for the result as follows:

```
name               | positions
----------------------------------------
John Smith         | member
Mary Jones         | chair,member
Grace Adams        | contact,director,member
Bill McDonnell     | treasurer,vice chair
Ishmael Rodriguez  | member
```

I was hoping I could use some variant of CONCAT_WS() to get my result, like this...

```
SELECT
a.NAME,
CONCAT_WS(
    ',',
    (
        SELECT
            position
        FROM
            TABLE
        WHERE
            NAME = a.NAME
    )
)AS positions FROM ---------------
```

Obviously, this isn't working out for me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[GROUP_CONCAT<sup>[docs]</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(position) result
FROM tableName
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY `index`
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe974/2)

Comment: [GROUP_CONCAT in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Wow... I never knew.  I feel silly sometimes in that I've taught myself, so some things still elude me.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) like so:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(position SEPARATOR ',')
FROM Table
GROUP BY name
```